# Eclipse IDE Run Configurations Environment Variables

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am configuring Eclipse to enable autocompletion for programming using rospy. So, can anyone please provide the Paths in Eclipse for the following Variables :

1. PATH
2. PYTHONPATH
3. ROS_MASTER_URI
4. ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
5. ROS_ROOT

I have followed all the steps from the tutorial here. http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs

But, when I run the test.py file, it gives an error saying "No Module named rospy"

I think, I am not setting the environment variables correctly. Hence, Please someone provide the environment variables you use so that I can correct the mistake if any.

Also, if somebody of you have any other suggestions, I would be pleased to know

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192384/eclipse-ide--run-configurations--environment-variables/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The settings for these will vary wildly based on your system, which version of ROS you're running, and possibly your workspace.

It may be better to extract them from your system by sourcing the setup.sh for your workspace and then inspecting the resulting environment.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-09-10**:
I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first paragraph of the wiki page you linked answers your question.

The easiest way to get the environment variables correctly inside eclipse is to run eclipse from a shell shell that sources your setup.bash.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2